# Is it possible to use std::basic_ifstream and std::basic_ofstream with a custom buffer?

Tags: c++

I cannot figure out, is it possible to use std::basic_ifstream and std::basic_ofstream with a custom implementation of std::basic_filebuf?

How complicated can be an implementation of an input file stream that reads the file by blocks of 64KB size and internally checks some hash value of the block? If the hash is not valid it throws corruption_exception, for example. The output file stream writes the block and the hash value after it.

I found some examples that creates std::ifstream and then creates another stream that reads from it and does additional processing:

```
std::ifstream infile("test.img");
decompress_stream in(infile, 288);
char data[144 * 128];
in.read(data, 144 * 128);
infile.close();
```

But at first I expected it should be something like this (without an additional stream):

```
std::ifstrem in;
in.setbuffer(new MyBuffer());
in.read();

MyBuffer::underflow()
{
     //read from original buffer
     if (hash != calculated_sash) throw curruption_exception();
     //return the data with omitted hash.
}
```

is this possible?

Comment: The way to do this without external libraries is to derive a class from `std::basic_filebuf` and use an object of that type as the buffer for a `basic_istream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file stream objects are effectively a combination of a `std::basic_filebuf` and a `std::basic_[io]stream`. The stream interface allows access to the `std::basic_streambuf` via the `rdbuf()` methods. Thus, you *can* replace the file stream stream buffer by another one. However, it wouldn’t have anything to do with the original file buffer.

As the stream buffer you have is a filtering stream buffer it may be reasonable to construct it with a stream and have the constructor inject the filter, i.e., something like this (I’m omitting the templates as these are irrelevant to this discussion but can easily be added):

```
class filterbuf
    : public std::streambuf {
    std::istream* istream = nullptr;
    std::ostream* ostream = nullptr;
    std::streambuf * sbuf;

    // override virtual functions as needed
public:
    explicit filterbuf(std::istream& in)
        : istream(&in)
        , sbuf(istream->rdbuf(this)) {
    }
    explict filterbuf(std::ostream& out)
        : ostream(&out)
        , sbuf(ostream->rdbuf(this)) {
    }
    explicit filebuf(std::iostream& inout)
        : istream(&inout)
        , sbuf(istream->rdbuf(this)) {
    }
    ~filebuf() {
        istream && istream->rdbuf(sbuf);
        ostream && ostream->rdbuf(sbuf);
    }
};
```

The point of restoring the stream buffer in the destructor is that the `std::ostream` destructor calls `flush()` on the object and the custom stream buffer is gone by that time.

The filter would be used like this:

```
std::istream fin(“whatever”);
filterbuf        buf(fin);
if (fin >> whatever) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customise the behaviour of iostreams the easiest way is to use [boost::iostreams](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html). Your use case could probably be implemented as an `Inputfilter` and an `OutputFilter`, you can use `basic_file_source` and `basic_file_sink` to read and write to files.